# CSS: Change the background color of a toggle element when toggled

Tags: css

This is my code to toggle an element

```
<label style="float:right" class="toggle toggle-assertive">
             <input type="checkbox" ng-model="checkModel">
             <div class="track">
               <div class="handle"></div> 
             </div>
</label>
```

This is the output of the above code
[image]
When the checkbox is toggled, the background element changes to red as shown
[image]
Now I want the background to change to blue when toggled so I have this code

```
#trackBack {
background-color:#0000FF;
border:0;
}
```

On applying the above css code the background changes to blue whether toggled or not. Shown in the below picture

[image]
My challenge now is how can I make the background blue only when toggled.
Kindly assist

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do following way.

**[Working Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/d00te80q/)**

```css
    .onoffswitch {
        position: relative; width: 60px;
        -webkit-user-select:none; -moz-user-select:none; -ms-user-select: none;
    }
    .onoffswitch-checkbox {
        display: none;
    }
    .onoffswitch-label {
        display: block; overflow: hidden; cursor: pointer;
        height: 36px; padding: 0; line-height: 36px;
        border: 2px solid #CCCCCC; border-radius: 36px;
        background-color: #FFFFFF;
        transition: background-color 0.3s ease-in;
    }
    .onoffswitch-label:before {
        content: "";
        display: block; width: 36px; margin: 0px;
        background: #FFFFFF;
        position: absolute; top: 0; bottom: 0;
        right: 22px;
        border: 2px solid #CCCCCC; border-radius: 36px;
        transition: all 0.3s ease-in 0s; 
    }
    .onoffswitch-checkbox:checked + .onoffswitch-label {
        background-color: #0000FF;
    }
    .onoffswitch-checkbox:checked + .onoffswitch-label, .onoffswitch-checkbox:checked + .onoffswitch-label:before {
       border-color: #0000FF;
    }
    .onoffswitch-checkbox:checked + .onoffswitch-label:before {
        right: 0px; 
    }
```

```html
    <div class="onoffswitch">
        <input type="checkbox" name="onoffswitch" class="onoffswitch-checkbox" id="myonoffswitch" checked>
        <label class="onoffswitch-label" for="myonoffswitch"></label>
    </div>
```

**[Reference link](https://proto.io/freebies/onoff/)**

Answer (score 0):

When you're using Jquery than you can use the toggleClass function. This changes the class of the html item that is selected.

This is the code of the Jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("button").click(function(){
        $("p").toggleClass("main");
    });
});
```

And here the code of the HTML:

```
<body>

<button>Toggle class "main" for p elements</button>

<p>This is a paragraph.</p>
<p>This is another paragraph.</p>
<p><b>Note:</b> Click the button more than once to see the toggle effect.</p>

</body>
```

And CSS:

```
.main {
    font-size: 120%;
    color: red;
}
```

Here is a JSfiddle to play with: 
[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/robbedillen/vv2w01ds/)